# Highcharts percentage lable missing

Tags: highcharts

I have a script that displays two sets of data as a bar chart left to right.
I would like to have the y axis display 100% under the chart. I currently display the percentage for both sets of data at the end of each bar.

If I add "max:100" to the yAxis property the chart only display one of the bars with the percentage[image]

Without the "max:100" in the yAxis property the chart display both percentages
[image]

the script looks like this:

```
$(function () {
$('#container1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Test'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },



    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -20,
        y: 34,
        floating: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
    series: {
        shadow:false,
        borderWidth:0,
        dataLabels:{
            enabled:true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y +'%';
            }
        }
    }
},
xAxis:{

    categories: [''],
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickLength:3,
    title:{
        text:'Test'
    },
},
yAxis:{

    max:100,
    showFirstLabel: false,
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickWidth:1,
    tickLength:3,
    gridLineColor:'#ddd',
    title:{
        text:'Between <?php print $_POST['FromDate'];?> and <?php print $_POST['ToDate'];?>',
        rotation:0,
        margin:50,
    },
    labels:
        {
        enabled: true
    }
},
    series: [{ first set of data
    },{

    second set of data

    }]
});
});
```

What I would like to have is the percentage 0% - 100% on the yAxis and the percentage of each bar at the end of the bar.

Can anyone help with this. Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a working fiddle of what you have now? when i paste that script into a fiddle i get nothing showing

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zh8t2cev/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/zgbwocnv/9/

Comment: The fiddle works but when I include the MySQL query to get the data it does not.

Comment: [<?php 
   mysql_select_db($database_n, $con);
   $query_result1 = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(Condition) AS RCL1 FROM Feed WHERE ConditionValue = 1 AND FeedBackDate BETWEEN '" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['FromDate'])) . "' AND '". date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['ToDate'])) . "'");
   $result1 = mysql_query($query_result1, $navex) or die(mysql_error());
   //$row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $totalRows_result1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
  
   while ($row_result1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
   ?>
   
   [<?php echo $row_result1['RCL1'];?>],
         
   <?php 
   }
   ?>
   ]

Comment: that's not very helpful

Comment: Post a fiddle with the actual result from your backend, so we can see if it's the backend or Highcharts.

Comment: Looks like a possible `allowOverlap` problem? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.allowOverlap

Comment: Set also a [padding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.padding) as 0.